# Python dictionary from a sequence

Tags: python, dictionary

```
my_dict = dict([(1,'apple'), (2,'ball')])
```

when I print my_dict the output is

```
{1: 'apple', 2: 'ball'}
```

How it's working?
I am new to python Please explain this

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That's just how the `dict` function works, I don't understand your question about it

Comment: are you trying to ask why it didn't print the brackets? like this `[(1,'apple'), (2,'ball')]`?

Comment: As per understanding about dict, dict is a key value pair like { key1 : value1, key2 : value2 } but it looks different for me that's why i am asking here

Comment: What Ofer Sadan said, although strictly speaking `dict` isn't a function, it's a class (sometimes called a type), so you are calling the constructor of that class, and passing that list of tuples to its initializer.

Comment: `{ key1 : value1, key2 : value2 }` is a `dict` literal. But you can also create a `dict` by calling its constructor, passing it any (finite) iterable of key-value pairs.

Comment: Now i am getting it thank you guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dictionary is data structure in Python. Think about it as an unordered(after python3.7 can be ordered) set of key: value pairs.
The values of a dictionary can be of any type, keys must be of an immutable data type such as strings, numbers, or tuples.
In your command, **dict()** used as constructor and **values([(1,'apple'), (2,'ball')])** is an **iterable object**.
Each item in the iterable is itself an iterable with exactly two objects. The first object of each item becomes a key in the new dictionary, and the second object the corresponding value.

Here is different representation of your example:

```
list_of_tuples = [(1,'apple'), (2,'ball')]
```

in order to create a dictionary, program will need to **iterate** thru the each value in the *list_of_tuples*

thats why you can use **dict()** **constructor** to do it, like so:

```
my_dict = dict(list_of_tuples)
```

Note that if a key occurs more than once, the last value for that key becomes the corresponding value in the new dictionary.

Comment: Ended up on this page and saw this answer, I am not knocking it down, but wanted to make it clear to anyone else that ends up here.....since 3.7 dictionaries are ordered. https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2017-December/151283.html

Answer (score 0):

When you create a dictionary you do with curly brackets, `{}`, with the keys and values separated by colons, `:`. Here's an example

```
my_dict = {
    1 : 'apple',
    2 : 'ball'
}
```

You can index this dictionary with square brackets as you've done in the question.

When you call print on this dictionary it prints it out in a similar fashion with the key followed a colon and the value, all encompassed within curly brackets.

```
{1: 'apple', 2: 'ball'}
```

If you would like to print a particular value in the dictionary you do so as follows

```
print my_dict[1]
```

This would print out the value associated with 1 in the dictionary which in our example is

```
apple
```